# MySQL between function with larger numbers

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project and i got a little stuck on this query i have.

```
SELECT *
FROM product_product
WHERE (`region` = 'Balearen' OR `region` = 'Ibiza' OR `city`='Ibiza') AND `price` BETWEEN '100' AND '1500' AND `published`='1'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1000
```

This only gets me two results, and when i choose an between of 100 and 999 i get the right results.

This gives me right results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_product 
WHERE (`region` = 'Balearen' OR `region` = 'Ibiza' OR `city`='Ibiza')
  AND `price` BETWEEN '100' AND '999' AND `published`='1' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1000
```

The prices are stored like this "102.00".

So my question is, why does the between clause act like this? am i doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it stored as string?

Comment: If your fields are stored as string its normal, you have to cast it as int to use Between properly

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the price is/was stored as varchar. I should put this to an DECIMAL(2,2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert you values to string that's why you get the wron result. remove the singleqoutes from the values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_product 
WHERE (`region` = 'Balearen' OR `region` = 'Ibiza' OR `city`='Ibiza') 
  AND `price` BETWEEN 100 AND 1500 AND `published`='1' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1000
```

Comment: right @GreenBlueRup you don't need the number values in quotations because it is interpreted as a string

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this fixed it for me and now I understand why.